# session in spring mvc spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, httpsession

How to manipulate session in spring mvc . I have searched in the network and I found that Spring MVCcould be the solution. But the problem is I can only pass two parameters of authentification (the username and the password)

```
<user-service>
    <user name="user" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</user-service>`
```

and in my case I must pass three parameters.I would be so grateful if I found the solution in this forum.

Comment: whats the third parameter ? Username and password are generally accepted to be adequate.

Comment: it is an integer variable . It should be correctly entered

Comment: whats the point of that ? It is involved in the authentication process somewhow  - if so it sounds very strange.

Comment: yes, it is involved in the authentification process

Comment: remove it, its weird and unnecessary

Comment: remove the third parameter. you can always use the authorities for authentication processes.